# Plain-text login with sendmail and SASL, Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail, ubuntu-10.04, sasl, smarthost

I'm trying to configure sendmail with a smarthost. I mostly followed this [guide](http://www.scalix.com/wiki/index.php?title=Configuring_Sendmail_with_smarthost_Ubuntu_Gutsy) (although I understand it is written for Scalix).

SMTP server uses plain-text authentication. However, when sendmail tries to relay an email, I see this error in sendmail.log:

```
May 17 01:55:28 myhost sm-mta[12153]: STARTTLS=client, relay=smtp.myserver.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
May 17 01:55:28 myhost sm-mta[12153]: s4GKkZNt010225: AUTH=client, available mechanisms do not fulfill requirements
May 17 01:55:28 myhost sm-mta[12153]: AUTH=client, relay=smtp.myserver.com., temporary failure, connection abort
May 17 01:55:28 myhost sm-mta[12153]: s4GKkZNt010225: to=<my@email>, delay=01:08:53, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=840427, relay=smtp.myserver.com.
```

Why does it try to use TLS?

After some googling, I understand it has something to do with SASL library. I saw several advices on installing `cyrus-sasl-plain` package, but it is not available in Ubuntu 10.04.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-modules
```

This installed several modules, including `liblogin` and `libplain` and now everything works fine.

Comment: Almost 3 years later this took me nearly 3 days to find this answer. Thanks.

Comment: I second @torvin on his answer. It is the only way I was able to get sendmail to cooperate with PostmarkApp. I am now able to send e-mail without issues. Prior to that I was getting the dreaded: AUTH=client, relay=xxxx.foo.bar, temporary failure, connection abort I tested in Ubuntu 20.04.